# How can I create a fluid and performant layout with CSS Grid and Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, css-grid

I'm currently working on a web project that requires a complex layout with multiple sections and elements. I want to use CSS Grid and Flexbox to achieve this, but I'm not sure how to create a fluid and performant layout that works well across different devices and screen sizes. Can you provide some tips and best practices for using CSS Grid and Flexbox to create a responsive and efficient layout?

Comment: Start with these guides:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here are some tips and examples you can follow:

1. Start with a mobile-first approach: Design for small screens first
   and gradually add complexity as screen size increases. Example:
   Start    by designing for a smartphone screen and then add elements
   for a    tablet and desktop.
2. Use CSS Grid to create the overall layout structure: Define grid columns and rows, and position elements within the grid.
   Example: Use    grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows to
   create a grid layout.
3. Use CSS Grid to create the overall layout structure: Define grid    columns and rows, and position elements within the grid.
   Example: Use    grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows to
   create a grid layout.
4. Use Flexbox to create flexible and responsive elements: Align and    justify contents of flex containers. Example: Use display:
   flex to turn an element into a flex container and justify-content
   and align-items to align contents.
5. Use media queries to adjust the layout for different screen sizes:    Apply different styles based on screen size. Example: Use
   @media    rules to adjust layout styles for tablet and desktop
   screens.
6. Use relative units for font sizes and dimensions: Use em or rem units    for font sizes and dimensions. Example: Use font-size:
   1em to set the    font size relative to the parent element.
7. Avoid using too many nested grids or flex containers: Minimize    nesting to improve performance. Example: Instead of
   nesting grids and    flex containers, use them together to create a
   complex layout.
8. Use the grid-auto-flow property to control item placement within the    grid: Specify how items should be placed in the grid.
   Example: Use    grid-auto-flow: dense to optimize item placement in
   the grid.